# How to search for an outlook contact through java program?

Tags: java, automation, outlook

Can any one give me a solution to automate finding a contact from MS Outlook using java?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will usually be configured to look up addresses from a centralised LDAP repository. You will get plenty of Java libraries to query and browse LDAP.

Comment: actually I have created a java code to add contacts to outlook using SWT OLE libraries. Now I want to eliminate the duplication while adding contacts. So i want to search for the mail id in the list. do you have any idea to get it done in a simple way?